# Use a period in a field name in a Matlab struct

Tags: json, matlab, struct

I'm using webwrite to post to an api. One of the field names in the json object I'm trying to setup for posting is `odata.metadata`. I'm making a struct that looks like this for the json object:

`json = struct('odata.metadata', metadata, 'odata.type', type, 'Name', name,);`

But I get an error

```
  Error using struct
  Invalid field name "odata.metadata"
```

Here's the json object I'm trying to use in Matlab. All strings for simplicity:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://website.com@Element",
    "odata.type": "Blah.Blah.This.That",
    "Name": "My Object"
}
```

Is there a way to submit this json object or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Assuming the API is able to work like that - maybe you could avoid this problem entirely by having an `odata` field in the topmost JSON object that contains another JSON object with the fields `metadata` and `type`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I did not make the api and I cannot control how the owners implement it.

Comment: I didn't say you need to change the API, just see if it works with a nested JSON object.

Comment: I only wish that MathWorks would stop using a "." for the many completely different actions that currently are valid.  Not only should there not be any operators (such as  `.*`), the structure, cell, etc. name delimiters should be some different symbol ( `R` uses `@` and `$`, for example).  A '`.`' is a decimal separator when numeric and otherwise should be a valid character in a string.  Period.  (pun intended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names are not allowed to have dots in them.  The reason why is because this will be confused with accessing another nested structure within the structure itself.

For example, doing `json.odata.metadata` would be interpreted as `json` being a `struct` with a member whose field name is `odata` where `odata` has another member whose field name is `metadata`.  This would **not** be interpreted as a member with the combined field name as `odata.metadata`.  You're going to have to rename the field to something else or change the convention of your field name slightly.

Usually, the convention is to replace dots with underscores.  An automated way to take care of this if you're not willing to manually rename the field names yourself is to use a function called [`matlab.lang.makeValidName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) that takes in a string and converts it into a valid field name.  This function was introduced in R2014a.  For older versions, it's called [`genvarname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html).

For example:

```
>> matlab.lang.makeValidName('odata.metadata')

ans =

odata_metadata
```

---

As such, either replace all dots with `_` to ensure no ambiguities or use `matlab.lang.makeValidName` or `genvarname` to take care of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) instead of a `struct` to store your data, and then creating your JSON string by iterating over the `Map` filednames and appending them along with the data to your JSON.

Here's a quick demonstration of what I mean:

```
%// Prepare the Map and the Data:
metadata = 'https://website.com@Element';
type = 'Blah.Blah.This.That';
name = 'My Object';
example_map = containers.Map({'odata.metadata','odata.type','Name'},...
                             {metadata,type,name});
%// Convert to JSON:
JSONstr = '{'; %// Initialization
map_keys = keys(example_map);
map_vals = values(example_map);
for ind1 = 1:example_map.Count
  JSONstr = [JSONstr '"' map_keys{ind1} '":"' map_vals{ind1} '",'];
end

JSONstr =[JSONstr(1:end-1) '}']; %// Finalization (get rid of the last ',' and close)
```

Which results in a valid JSON string.

Obviously if your `values` aren't strings you'll need to convert them using `num2str` etc.

---

Another alternative you might want to consider is the [JSONlab FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files-in-matlab-octave). I saw that its `savejson.m` is able to accept cell arrays - which can hold any string you like.

---

Other alternatives may include any of the numerous `Java` or `python` JSON libraries which you can call from MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I probably shouldn't add this as an answer - but you **can** have '.' in a struct fieldname...

**Before I go further - I do not advocate this and it will almost certainly cause bugs and a lot of trouble down the road... @rayryeng method is a better approach**

If your struct is created by a mex function which creates a field that contains a "." -> then you will get what your after.

To create your own test see the [Mathworks example](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97352-how-do-i-create-a-structure-array-from-a-c-mex-file-and-pass-it-to-matlab) and modify accordingly.

*(I wont put the full code here to discourage the practice).*

If you update the char example and compile to test_mex you get:

```
>> obj = test_mex

obj = 

       Doublestuff: [1x100 double]
    odata.metadata: 'This is my char'
```

Note: You can *only* access your custom field in Matlab using dynamic fieldnames:

```
obj.('odata.metadata')
```

You need to use a mex capability to update it...

Comment: Wow... I guess I was wrong... using MEX to go and do this lol. Very nice. +1.